# How to make the background of a pygame sprite transparent

Tags: python, pygame

This is supposed to just load a sprite onto the screen, but the background of the image is this black box, and i don't want to see that. How do I make the background of the image transparent?

```
from Tkinter import *
import pygame
from livewires import games

#Creating screen window
games.init(screen_width = 700, screen_height = 650, fps = 50)

#creating background image for the screen
screen_background = games.load_image('resized_stars background.png', transparent = False)
games.screen.background = screen_background

#Creating a sprite
spaceship_image = games.load_image('pixel_spaceship.png')
spaceship = games.Sprite(image = spaceship_image, x=350, y=235)
games.screen.add(spaceship)

#main loop at the end of the program just as in tkinter
games.screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image needs to be a [png](/questions/tagged/png). Open Preview, for example, and use the alpha tool to remove the background, thus adding transparency.

**Before [png](/questions/tagged/png)**:

[image]

**After [png](/questions/tagged/png)**:

[image]

Look [here](http://www181.lunapic.com/editor/?action=transparent) for a tool on making your picture transparent.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry if it was a stupid question. But I was using Adobe Photoshop to get rid of the background, and when i loaded the image into the program, it had this weird background that was black and multicolored with transparent blotches. So why doesn't Photoshop work?

Answer (score 0):

When loading the png image, you have to convert it:

```
image = pygame.image.load("yourImage.png").convert_alpha()
```

This should get rid of that black box that should be the transparent alpha.